# Getting error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" in Mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating following query but it gives error:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE WhileLoopProc10()
   BEGIN


      SET @s=(SELECT *  FROM registrationnew  where refid=0);

   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

but if I write only select statement without @s it works fine but I want to display result of @s.

Comment: Like you can read from that error, you can get only one column using this way.

Answer (score 0):

Select only one column. Moreover, your query should return only one row. You will again get error if the query returns multiple rows.
If you are sure which row you need, get that row by using ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses.

Comment: thanks understood my mistake but how can i call multiple row in above procedure

Comment: You cannot select multiple rows while assigning value to a variable. If that is a requirement, you need to run a loop and assign it using cursor.